# cannot find symbol PreparedStatement after JAR upgrade

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jar, prepared-statement

I just upgraded mysql jdbc connection JAR (from mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar to mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar) and the project started showing error for import statements:

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;

java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PreparedStatement
  location: class package.ClassName
```

Where to find the location or package for PreparedStatement in new jar file or is it replaced with any other class in new JAR?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean [`java.sql.PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)?

Comment: @khelwood - Could you please help to understand? Do you mean `import com.mysql.jdbc.*` is now repalced with `import java.sql.*` with new JAR files? (I'm not a professional Java developer, so not much aware about this package changes.)

Comment: No, I mean the only `PreparedStatement` type in Java I've ever had to use is `java.sql.PreparedStatement`, and maybe that was the type you were looking for.

Comment: Actully I've `import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;` in my project, which was working fine until I upgraded JDBC connection jar file to `mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar`. What can be it's resolution

Comment: It was perhaps a mistake to `import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement` - when working with JDBC, you usually only code against the `java.sql` interfaces.

Comment: @GyroGearless - Thank you for clarification.. The project source code I've is around 7-8 years old, which we are upgrading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace it with:

```java
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
```

Using `com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement` is specific to mysql, and should not be imported directly.

So unless you need MySQL specific features, it's always better to use the interface `java.sql.PreparedStatement` that is database independent. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065464/what-is-the-difference-between-package-com-mysql-jdbc-preparedstatement-and-jav).

Comment: So do you mean import com.mysql.jdbc.* is now replaced with import java.sql.* with new JAR file mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar?

Comment: @Krunal It has always been better to import the `java.sql.*` interfaces instead of the MySQL implementation classes, you're now just confronted with this previous mistake to import the wrong class because MySQL moved and renamed a lot of the implementation classes in MySQL Connector/J.

Answer (score 4):

`com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement` is an internal class to the MySQL 5.x JDBC driver.  Your code should not import it.  It should be using the standard `java.sql.PreparedStatement` class instead.

The package names have changed in the MySQL 8.x JDBC drivers, and that is what caused your code to start giving compilation errors.

Solution:

1. Fix your code so that it doesn't import any MySQL implementation classes<sup>1</sup>.  Use the `java.sql.*` and `javax.sql.*` class instead.
2. Change your project dependencies so that the MySQL driver JAR is not a compile-time dependency.  Doing that will cause any *accidental* source code dependencies on JDBC drivers to be flagged as compilation errors.  It will also stop your IDE from making incorrect suggestions for `import` statements.  (My guess is that that is how the bogus import got into your codebase.)
3. If your code is (still) using `Class.forName` to load the JDBC driver, change it to use `java.sql.DriverManager` instead; see [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html).  That way you won't be burned by another change in the MySQL driver class name.

---

<sup>1 - Your Java code should not *need* to depend on MySQL-specific APIs.  As far as I know, the MySQL implementation classes mirror the standard JDBC APIs, so you gain nothing by using them directly.  This is not true for all vendors.</sup>

Comment: In general you are right, but sometimes using the implementation specific classes or interfaces may be necessary to access features not specified in JDBC (vendor-specific extensions).

Comment: I don't think that is true for MySQL.  I recall that (ahem) some old Oracle JDBC drivers required you to do that kind of thing.  Maybe Postgres too.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have many of them, but for example you might want to cast or unwrap to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.JdbcStatement` to access the `setLocalInfileInputStream` method. And the `JdbcConnection` interface contains some methods that are - I think - primarily for internal use, but may be helpful in some cases.